# Why did the EU and USA really impose sanctions on Zimbabwe?

Tags: sanctions, sovereignty, zimbabwe

The EU and USA first imposed economic sanctions against Zimbabwe in 2002. After that these sanctions have been renewed on a regular basis.

- What was the root cause of these sanctions?
- What is the justification given for renewing these sanctions till now?
- Do these sanctions impinge on the sovereignty of Zimbabwe?

Apart from the camouflage of the official justifications specified in the economic sanctions declarations, what is the political/geo-strategic goal that the EU and USA want to achieve by the imposition of these sanctions?

Most of these sanctions text talk about *Human Rights Violations and undermining of Democracy*. What exactly are these Violations? Are there any specific examples that can be pointed or events that point to a trend?

Comment: We can only tell you the justifications that the EU and the USA have openly given. Asking us to speculate about whether there's some kind of hidden, secret agenda behind the sanctions is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: The USA openly gave the explanation of WMD in their invasion of Iraq. Should trying to find out the real reason why it invaded Iraq also be off-topic? Russia open gives the justification of De-Nazifying Ukraine for its invasion of Ukraine. Should discussing the real reason of the Russia's invasion of Ukraine, also be considered off-topic?

Comment: @ksinkar I can't really disagree with your argument there, but aside from that, this question has way to many questions in it. You should focus it down to the core question "Why did the US/EU impose sanction on Zimbabwe?" and remove the parts of the question that imply or assume that they are lying. Leave it to the answerers to point out additional factors that may have influenced this beyond the official statements.

Comment: "Apart from the camouflage of the official justifications specified in the economic sanctions declarations" before simply assuming that the government doesn't mean what it says, you really ought to make some effort to substantiate that claim.

Answer (score 1):

Zimbabwe had been a one party dictatorship under Mugabe for a long while.  And those are the official reasons.

The actual reasons **are** those **and** the recurring murders and expropriation of white farmers in Zimbabwe.  In order to give the land over to Zanu-pf cronies of Mugabe's.

This was *extensively* covered by international press at the time and anyone could draw their own conclusions as to the relation between that coverage and the imposition of sanctions.

A date-limited [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=white%20farmers%20killed%20zimbabwe%20&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_max%3A3%2F1%2F2002&sxsrf=APq-WBtdX6CrkTXj6xmy0ytXdOUNqCxSgw%3A1646412358235) shows that easily enough.  For [example](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/opposition-reports-new-attacks-as-white-farm-owner-killed-1.268835):

> A hit squad has murdered another white farmer, Mr Alan Dunn, in Zimbabwe. Six men dragged him from his home on his farm near Beatrice, 35 miles south of Harare, on Sunday and bludgeoned him with concrete blocks and bricks. In less than 10 minutes Mr Dunn was unconscious in a pool of blood with a fractured skull, two broken arms and internal injuries. He died early yesterday. The political killing provides fresh evidence that President Robert Mugabe is maintaining a campaign of state-sponsored violence against opposition supporters.
>
> Mr Dunn's death brings to 19 the number of backers of the Movement for Democratic Change (MDC) killed by Mr Mugabe's supporters since April 1st. The dead include white farmers, black farm labourers, city residents and peasants.

I.e. sanctions may or may not have been on the horizon, but frequent lurid reports of actual violence against people who may have had family and acquaintances in the UK and other Western countries kept this on the fire until it boiled over and sanctions were instated.

Similar murders have happened in South Africa but they seem more due to general criminal activity, whereas those in Zimbabwe were apparently tolerated by the government and were in a context of expropriations.

p.s. while one could question why white farmers had such large land holdings, it remains true that those were the most productive farms in Zimbabwe by far and that Mugabe's cronies [ran them into the ground](https://qz.com/africa/1152276/zimbabwes-white-farmers-kicked-out-by-mugabe-will-be-compensated-by-mnangagwa/) once they took over, contributing to Zimbabwe's overall woes.